# setImageResource (int) in TouchImageView cannot be applied to (long)

Tags: android, gridview, picasso

I'm using Picasso Library to load images from several Urls in a `GridView`. Now I want to be able to see the images in fullscreen, for so I added a `clickListener`. The problem is in the FullScreen Activity in this line: `fi.setImageResource(gv.getItemId(position))` -> `setImageResource (int) in TouchImageView cannot be applied to (long)`

```
public class FullScreen extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        SampleGridViewAdapter gv = new SampleGridViewAdapter(this);

        final TouchImageView fi = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_img);
        fi.setImageResource(gv.getItemId(position));

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(gv.getItem(position))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .fit().centerInside()
                .into(fi);
    }
}
```

Also check this link, that guy had the same issue but I can't find a way to fix it: [Android Picasso GridView - Store URL data in Integer array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156001/android-picasso-gridview-store-url-data-in-integer-array)

**EDIT:** - this is what I get now when I run the app.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zenyt/com.zenyt.FullScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.zenyt.FullScreen.onCreate(FullScreen.java:16) // line: int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the fragment from where I call the FullScreen activity:

```
public class Audi2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(com.zenyt.R.layout.audi2, container, false);

        GridView gv = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gv.setAdapter(new SampleGridViewAdapter(getActivity()));
        gv.setOnScrollListener(new SampleScrollListener(getActivity()));

        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), FullScreen.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }
        });

       return rootView;
    }
```

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not passing in the bundle to your activity. So when you try to get "id" it is not there. Create and add the bundle in your `onClick` like so:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
      //create bundle
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      //add data to your bundle
      bundle.putInt("id", position);
      //create intent
      Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), FullScreen.class);
      //add bundle to intent
      mainIntent.putExtras(bundle);
      //start activity
      startActivity(mainIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`gv.getItemId()` will return the id of the grid view, which is a `long`. Not the resource id. Consider getting the resource another way. Maybe you meant to do this instead?

```
fi.setImageResource(gv.getItem(position));  //not getItemId
```

**Unless** you have set your `gv.getItemId()` to return the resource id. If that is the case, then just cast to int.

```
 fi.setImageResource((int) gv.getItemId(position));
```

Comment: The second line ( casting the int ) doesn't give me any error but when I launch the app and press on an image, it crashes. I think it's because of this line `int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");` . I'm doing something wrong. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I see. How are you starting this activity?

Comment: I added the fragment from which I call the FullScreen activity.

Comment: When you call the activity are you adding the bundle to the activity? post that code

Comment: Should I do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I figured you were.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69967/discussion-between-binghammer-and-masterz-yuri).